# How to send http request coming to EBS to https request?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon Web service for deployment of my applications
Can somebody tell me how should i configure load balancer so that it will redirect each HTTP request to HTTPS to my EBS server application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are talking about more than port forwarding (i.e. forwarding requests on port 80 on ELB to 443 on EC2), but rather actually redirecting the request to https such that the user's browsers gets the rewritten URL. Is this correct?

Comment: basically i want following behaviour
if user hits http://www.myweb.com
then automatically it should redirect to https://www.myweb.com
So i want only HTTPS version of my website & i dont want use to go with http

Comment: OK. Then this is likely to be a matter of configuring your web server to make this redirection.  I would suggest adding information on the web server you are using to your question and add a tag for it as well.